# Battery Drain from mysterious wake locks

Tags: battery, battery-life, oneplus-one, wakelock, greenify

I have an huge battery drain issue on my OnePlus One running Android 4.4.2 on stock ROM CM11s O5Q with FrancoKernel R35. I googled and searched so many times but couldn't find anything and I am really desperated now. And hope you guys can help me out.

So, some time ago I noticed that my battery drains over night in "Deep Sleep" 2-8% per hour which is really unusual. I installed "BetterBatteryStats" to look up whats going on, noticing that strange wakelocks are draining my phones battery. Here are to wakelocks event0-875 and event2-875 (see screenshot, this screenshot was taken after charging so dont wonder the -0,5%) which iI dont know and I also dont know to what they belong to.

I read so far that event0 are androidOS stuff wakelocks and at the end of a day I have round about 30-40% left mainly drained buy AndroidOS, as I can see from the built-in Bettery Stats. We have to see that its a 3100mAh battery and i usually dont use my phone at all during the day.

I already greenified some apps to see if its an app which is causing the drain but no success so far.

Today in the evening I cant post you another screenshot from WakelockDetector app. The statistics resets after charging the phone.

I hope you guys can help me, thanks so far!

[image: BetterBatteryStats]
<sup>BetterBatteryStats (click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: does rebooting/restart the phonef fix it temperary?

Comment: No I tried it several times inlcuding clearing cache and stuff at the end of a day the same result showed up

Comment: what if no internet access ( OS update )?

Comment: I dont understand the question :) I am usually all day connected to WLAN. The phone turns WLAN of if not necessary and in sleep i guess

Comment: check 'data usage'. can you see 'android OS' in the list.

Comment: I see Android System with 8.5MB

Comment: possible OS update. Can you try this : recharge to 100%, switch to flight mode , restart phone. watch for some hours/day.

Answer (score 0):

If you're rooted, try **Greenify**. It will hibernate all the unused apps and thereby releasing resources which sucks up your battery juice.